# SortMemberPath property does not exist on Windows Community Toolkit's Datagrid (WinUI3 desktop app) on Windows 11

Tags: c#, windows, datagrid, winui-3

I'm trying to make my datagrid be able to be sorted. I have set "CanUserSortColumns" to True, and I have tried solutions to set the SortMemberPath on the column so it can be sorted.

But my datagrid doesn't contain SortMemberPath property. When I type "sort", it only shows "CanUserSort" and "SortDirection" properties. There's nothing else.

Maybe I'm using the wrong Nuget package? I'm using CommunityToolkit.WinUI.UI.Controls and CommunityToolkit.WinUI.UI.Controls.DataGrid.

Here's my datagrid code on MainWindow.xaml:

```
<controls:DataGrid
  Grid.Row="1"
    x:Name="dataGrid"
    Margin="12"
    VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
    HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
    VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
    AlternatingRowBackground="Transparent"
    AlternatingRowForeground="LightGray"
    AreRowDetailsFrozen="False"
    AreRowGroupHeadersFrozen="False"
    AutoGenerateColumns="True"
    CanUserSortColumns="True"
    CanUserReorderColumns="True"
    CanUserResizeColumns="True"
    ColumnHeaderHeight="32"
    MaxColumnWidth="400"
    FrozenColumnCount="0"
    GridLinesVisibility="None"
    IsReadOnly="False"
    RowDetailsTemplate="{StaticResource RowDetailsTemplate}"
    RowDetailsVisibilityMode="Collapsed"
    SelectionMode="Single"
    AutoGeneratingColumn="autogenerating"
            HeadersVisibility="Column">
            <controls:DataGrid.Columns>
                <controls:DataGridTextColumn Header="wow"></controls:DataGridTextColumn>
            </controls:DataGrid.Columns>
        </controls:DataGrid>
```

Here's the screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kNKF4.png

Is there a way to sort datagrid without relying on "SortMemberPath"? What did I miss?

Comment: Community Toolkit is for WinUI2/UWP I believe, not WinUI3

Comment: The correct way is to sort the CollectionView that sits between the grid and your collection.